# Access/Excel VBA: Variable number of worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

My current AccessDB creates a new XLS workbook with 3 XLS worksheets.  No problem.

Turns out I need to accommodate a variable number of worksheets, but I am at a loss how to create and then reference the individual worksheets.

Currently I create and populate/format the worksheet explicitly (snippet from my app for first 2 Tabs):

```
Private Sub btnReport_Click()

Dim appXLS As Object
Dim wbk, rng As Object
Dim wks1, wks2, wks3 As Object
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb
Set appXLS = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wbk = appXLS.Workbooks.Add(1)

appXLS.Visible = True
wbk.Activate

'Create Tab 1

Set wks1 = wbk.ActiveSheet
wbk.Sheets(1).NAME = TempVars!my_InvID

' Populate XLS from query/recordset

strSQL = "q_chgSummary"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

With wks1
    .range("A" & n).CopyFromRecordset rs
End With

'Format Tab 1
appXLS.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
wks1.range("A1").Value = "Summary Report"
'...other formatting

' Create Tab_2

Set wks2 = wbk.Sheets.Add(After:=wbk.Sheets(wbk.Sheets.COUNT))
wbk.Sheets(2).NAME = "Matched Items"

strSQL = "q_chgMatched"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set wks2 = wbk.ActiveSheet

wbk.SaveAs Filename:=myFile

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Can anyone offer any pointers to adjust this process to insert a variable number of worksheets, known only at runtime.  I presume I'll use the .index property, but I am not clear how to handle the explicit wks1 & wks2 type references.

Suggestions welcome, thank you!

Comment: What determines the number of sheets needed?

Comment: why isn't it known until runtime? I am guessing you will need a way to specify how many as the end point for a loop. Within that loop you add sheets, name them etc.

Comment: if it is in relation to row count that can be used to calculate number of sheets.

Comment: User will select a collection of options from a multi-select picklist.  This list will determine the number of Tabs (1 Tab per selection).  So, I will know the number when user clicks "Report".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only need one reference to a worksheet at a time, you can just reuse the same worksheet object.

This is sample code. Of course, you can use a list box instead of an array. This code doesn't populate the first sheet, you might want to adjust it accordingly.

```
Private Sub btnReport_Click()
Dim appXLS As Object
Dim wbk, rng, wks As Object
Dim arrQueries() As Variant

Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Set appXLS = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wbk = appXLS.Workbooks.Add(1)

arrQueries = Array("q_chgSummary", "q_chgMatched")
Dim vQuery As Variant
For Each vQuery In arrQueries
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset (vQuery)
    Set wks = wbk.Sheets.Add
    wks.Cells(1,1).CopyFromRecordset rs
Next

wbk.SaveAs Filename:=myFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank Erik, this helps.  Success inserting the next new sheet and populating via the rs.  Next I need to address specific cells in each Tab to insert formatting and additional formulas.  Can you suggest the the proper form to reference (example:  Cell A1 on each of the Tabs)?